# Understanding a concept in Java

Tags: java, android

I have started studying "Beginning Android Application Development". I came across this code below.
I am very new to Java, can somebody please explain how the author is calling different methods using the dot-operator without having to use the reference variable and class name.?
What concept in java is the author referring to?

```
case 0:
return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
.setTitle(“This is a dialog with some simple text...”)
.setPositiveButton(“OK”, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
    “OK clicked!”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Essentially each method call returns the object itself so you can call another method on the returned value.

APIs that implement method chaining are often said to provide a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Answer (score 0):

this is the ->`new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` here

it's equivalent to calling this function

```
setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
setTitle(“This is a dialog with some simple text...”)
setPositiveButton()
```

**Method Chaning**:

method chaining is a technique for invoking multiple method calls. It can make code more readable and help provide a fluent interface. Method chaining is sometimes overused, and can make debugging difficult hence the term 'train wreck'. I find method chaining most useful when setting properties of an object.

**example**:
this is method chaning.

```
person.setName("Peter").setAge(21).introduce();
```

this is not a method chaning

```
person.setName("Peter");
person.setAge(21);
person.introduce();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all considered a one line of code until the final semi-colon after all the brackets are closed. It is just spaced so for readability, otherwise it would have been a long line of code.